# Comparing two WordPress installations

Tags: customization

I searched a lot trying to find a solution to this. Hope someone may have an answer.

I have two Wordpress installations that supposedly are identical. One is on a production site and the other is on a staging site. The installation on the production site has some persistent bug that does not appear in my staging site.

Is there an efficient way I can compare the installations of both Wordpress sites so I can try to identify what differences may exist and perhaps troubleshoot the error?

Thank you very much,
Nabil

Comment: Did you find a solution, Nabil?

Answer (score 4):

I assume from your question that the 'bug' is an operational thing, not a code failure.

So, you can write some PHP code that will put the file hashes of every file of the first site into a database. Then compare those hashes with the hashes from the other site.

Any difference in files will show up as different hashes....but it won't tell you *what* the differences are.

So a second option is to 'diff' the two sets of files. This should find and highlight the differences.

The creation of either of these solutions is up to you.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of bug you are getting on production site. 
Also write this code on your staging site wp-config.php file

```
define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );
```